# How do you have two fonts in one UITextView (Xcode)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make two font styes in one UITextView, how do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have two on the same page because it is not supported. Just use a webview and an HTML file

Answer (score 5):

From the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html):

> This class does not support multiple styles for text. The font, color,
>   and text alignment attributes you specify always apply to the entire
>   contents of the text view. To display more complex styling in your
>   application, you need to use a UIWebView object and render your
>   content using HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can know use this by using the attributedText property of UITextView. This is available under iOS 6

Answer (score 0):

UITextView supports just a single font, but there's a different topic on something similar:
[Can I use multiple font style in UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846836/can-i-use-multiple-font-style-in-uitextview)

If the text you want to draw is simple, I'd suggest subclassing UITextView or UIView, overwriting the drawRect function and work with some extra variables of your own. This only works if you have a very predictable system to the fonts though.

Another option is using multiple labels, which would probably need an ever more predictable setup.

Comment: The labels take too long, that's why I changed to UITextViews but they're not all thumbs up either. Will apple ever make xcode easier to use?

Comment: Are you using xib? Since placing all the labels like that would indeed take forever. You can make them yourself programmatically with loops and arrays of data (frames, text, fonts) though. That way, you'll get as many labels as you like at with just a few lines of code.

Comment: Correction: A few lines of code for the loop. If you use arrays with the data as well, you'll still get to type the data for every entry. But if there's no mathemetical pattern in the data, you won't avoid that anyway. However, if they're in a grid or something, you can use the index of the loop to determine their frame mathematically.