# How to change Font Styles For iphone app?

Tags: iphone, uitextview, uifont

I need to change the font style from bold to italic,by using two buttons.for ex, i  am entering  the text "this is my iphone application ", after the string "this is"i would like to change the text from bold to italic  ( by clicking italic button )  while the previous one remains same.This should apply  every time for the button click actions,here is my code

```
-(IBAction)BoldClicked{
    textView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
}
-(IBAction)ItalicClicked{
 textView.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
}
```

But the total text is changing..Should I use web view for this?

Comment: Two different UITextView or UIWebView with some script

Comment: @beryllium sorry i did not get you

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6008832/845115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two different fonts in one UITextView. You can either use two different UITextViews, or use a UIWebview.

Comment: Can please  u give me any Example Code for that?i tried this by using web view,          self.htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@</b></i>",self.htmlString];  but  </b></i> this string is printing rather than the enter string from key board.

Comment: @prasanna see this [WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

Comment: put your html file in resource folder

Comment: @Marvin I don't Have such files, I need to enter text manually from keyboard into a text View or Something else  to show the Text.(some one suggested to use webview intead of text View)

Comment: Yeah You can't have two different fonts in one UITextView, For that You can use UIWebView

Comment: Create dynamic string for that and display it in UIWebView

Answer (score 0):

Normal UILabels do not support rich text (mixing of font styles and regular, bold, italic, etc in a single label).

A webview will let you use HTML, but will add a lot of performance overhead and potentially other issues.

You can do this using Core Text but that's quite a low level library and tricky to use.

You might want to consider using a 3rd party rich text label class. You can find a few such projects if you Google for them. Here's one for example: http://www.chupamobile.com/products/details/326/Rich+Text+Label/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much many times you are having to do this, then I would just add UILabel  subviews to the button, one for each font type.

Comment: I want to apply this for a continuous text(entering from keyboard) ,and changing the style according to my desire by using the buttons.